# Form not responding to click in mobile layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

So I have my site: https://enigmatic-woodland-92793.herokuapp.com/ mostly up and running, the problem is the form for the sign-up and login page does not work when viewed from the 768px and 360px(my phone size) viewports in the chrome dev tools.

I added a meta-tag

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

        <title>WorldScoop</title>
        <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../public/assets/css/reset.css"> -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/css/style.css">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href=/assets/images/favicon.jpg type="image/x-icon" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=768"/>

        <!-- <meta name="viewport" content="width=360"> -->
    </head>
```

which gives me the layout I want however the forms for the login and signup do not respond when clicked.

Here is the html for my form:

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 lorem">
            <div class="about">
                <form action="/login" method="post" style="padding-top: 20px" >
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>username</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Password</label>
                        <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control">
                        <a href="#" style="color:blue">forgot password?</a>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <!-- <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button> -->
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and media query:

```
@media handheld, screen and (max-width: 768px){

    /*.container{*/
        /*width: 100%;*/
        /*height: 100%;*/
    /*}*/
    .secondbipsum{
        position: relative;
        padding-left: 50px;
    }

    #profcard{
        /*position: absolute;*/
        width: 400px;
        /*margin*/
    }

    .dropdown{
        position: absolute;
        left: -100px;
    }

    #savedArticles{
        width: 300px;
    }

    #rightside{
        width: 300px;
    }

    #nav-profile{
        position: fixed;
        top: -20px;

    }

    .navbar{
        max-width: 768px;

        position: absolute;
        top: -15px;

    }



    .about{
        position: absolute;
        width: 780px;
        height: 330px;
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-left: 30px;
        padding-right: 50px;
        background-color: #03B3CE;
        margin-top: 230px;
        right: -12px;
        top:0px;
        /*margin-right: 10px;*/
        float: right;
        z-index: 0;
    }
    .carousel{
        position: absolute;
        width: 768px;
        height: 600px;
        margin-top: 85px;
        right: 0px;
        clear: right;
        float: right;
        z-index: 0;
    }

    .bipsum{
        width: 768px;
        position: relative;
        height: 920px;
    }



    .lorem{
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        margin-top: 400px;

        z-index: -1;
    }

    #title{
        margin-left: 5px;
    }

    #desc{
        margin-left: -40px;
        text-align: left;
    }

    .nav-item{
        font-size: 11px;
    }

    .fa-sign-out{
    /*margin-top: 10px;*/
    margin-right: 80px;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    bottom: 30px;
    }

}
```

I searched for quite a while on the internet and could not find anything for my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do these correction :

for `.lorem` change the z-index and margin-top so you have this CSS under 768px :

```
.lorem {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 640px;
    z-index: 0;
    height: auto;
}
```

for the `.about` remove completely the **margin-top** under 768px

I only suggest these correction to avoid the issue you are having but a better suggestion is to re-think the whole site as the HTML/CSS is very badly written !

Comment: Solution worked for me! Thank you. What would you suggest on the html and css part?

Comment: I see you are using bootstrap so i suggest you to study it more in order to understand how to create all the layouts you need. and avoid adding class to the Bootstrap ones as you will create confusion. Like `lorem` for example with `col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6`. You can do 90% of what you need using only the bootstrap class ... also don't forget to mark this answer as accepted to close the topic ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think you could have a look with the dev tools, the ".frontipsum" div overlaps the form part.